# Eclipse : Hot Code Replace Failed

Tags: java, eclipse, virtual-machine

Any idea why this is happening? I am using OSX Maverick and Eclipse.

[image]
I have no Add method used in my program and I don't see the reason it's nagging about it.

Comment: This is just a common warning you get when you start your container in debug mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to restart the Eclipse. I had this problem too and it works.

"The debugger issue is a restriction of the Eclipse hot-swap JPDA/JVM mechanism. Presently there is a limitation to how much a class may be modified and still be replaceable through the JPDA. My understanding is that can the shape of a class may not be modified, i.e., add/remove fields or methods. The "may be out of sync" warning indicates the change to a class within Eclipse has not been replaced in the server's JVM. To resolve this problem you must restart your server. In the near future we are planning to add an application RELOAD feature that we believe will workaround this problem. " ------myEclipseide.com

http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-583-highlight-shape.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that JVM run by Eclipse is not the same as the JVM running your Java application.